# JavaScript Requiring More Time Than Expected

Tags: javascript, performance

I'm attempting to generate a set of values every millisecond.

By using window.performance.now(), I've determined that 1000 points (1 second worth of data) requires approximately 1 millisecond worth of processing time.

So... why is a log statement generated every 3-ish seconds rather than every 1 second when my condition for generating the statement is that I have generated 1000 points?

The code is included below. And here is a link to jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/MWadX/421/

```
var c = 0;
var m = 0;
var t = 0;
var x = 0;
var y = 0;

window.setInterval(function()
{
        var e;
        var s;

        if (c === 0)
        {
          m = Date.now();
        }

        s = window.performance.now();

        x += Math.random();
        y += Math.random();
        c++;

        e = window.performance.now();
        t += e - s;

        if (c !== 1000)
        {
          return;
        }

        console.log(t.toFixed(0).toString() + " milliseconds");
        console.log((Date.now() - m).toFixed(0).toString() + " milliseconds");

        c = 0;
        m = 0;
        t = 0;
        x = 0;
        y = 0;
}, 1);
```

Comment: Justin tip, if you're assigning the same value to multiple variables, you can do it in one line. So you could do `c=m=t=c=y=0;` rather than what you did

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## `setInterval`, `setTimeout`, and Minimum Timeouts

According to the Mozilla Development Network [setInterval](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers/setInterval) and [setTimeout](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers/setInterval) have a minimum timeout. This value varies somewhat between browsers, but [the HTML5 spec specifies a minimum timeout of 4ms](https://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/timers.html#timers), and this value is pretty well respected in browsers made after 2010. If you pass a lower timeout, it will be internally inflated to the minimum.

## Inactive Tabs

In background tabs, the timeout is restricted even further to a minimum of 1000ms.

Comment: Excellent! Thanks for the clarification. I updated the interval to 5 milliseconds, reduced the count to 200, and now I'm getting results which are much more reasonable.